# MLeap serializeToBundle error for Pyspark custom Transformer

Tags: pyspark, mleap

I have a Pyspark custom Transformer that I am trying to serialize to an mLeap bundle object for later model scoring but I’m getting the following error:

```
---> 42         self._java_obj.serializeToBundle(transformer._to_java(), path, dataset._jdf)
     43
     44     def deserializeFromBundle(self, path):

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py in _to_java(self)
    314         java_stages = gateway.new_array(cls, len(self.stages))
    315         for idx, stage in enumerate(self.stages):
--> 316             java_stages[idx] = stage._to_java()
    317
    318         _java_obj =\

AttributeError: 'MyCustomTransformer' object has no attribute '_to_java'
```

My custom transformer inherits from `pyspark.ml.Transformer` but it seems as if there needs to be a `_to_java()` implementation for the mleap serialization to work ?

What are my options ?